# What is the best way to merge styles when wrapping Fabric components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

Consider I am wrapping a Fabric component where I apply some styles and want to merge any passed in styles from its props.
The best I could come up with is:

```
const { TextField, Fabric , IButtonProps, mergeStyleSets } = window.Fabric;

const MyTextField = (props: IButtonProps) => {
  const  { styles, ...otherProps } = props;

  const myStyles = stylesProps => {
    // props.styles can be a function, an object or undefined
    const stylesAsObject = typeof (styles) === "function" ? styles(stylesProps) : styles;
    return mergeStyleSets({ root: { maxWidth: 250 }, field: { backgroundColor: "pink"}}, stylesAsObject);
  };

  return <TextField styles={myStyles} {...otherProps} />;
}

const TextFieldExample () => (<MyTextField readOnly value="My text field" styles={{field: { fontWeight: 600}}} />
  );

ReactDOM.render(<Fabric><TextFieldExample /></Fabric>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

[This works](https://codepen.io/onlyann/pen/abOwBew?editors=1111) but is a bit verbose.

Is there some version of mergeStylesets where I could instead write:

```
const myStyles = mergeStylesets({ root: { maxWidth: 250 }, field: { backgroundColor: "pink"}}, props.styles);
```

Comment: I don't quite understand you question. Is it similar to merge objects by `Object.assign()`?

Comment: @JimJin There are utility functions in the [UI-Fabric](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react) to merge CSS-in-JS styles. This is not a generic Javascript question but rather a question on UI Fabric API.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered `concatStyleSetsWithProps` :

```
const { TextField, Fabric , IButtonProps, concatStyleSetsWithProps } = window.Fabric;

const MyTextField = (props: IButtonProps) => {
  return <TextField  {...props} styles={stylesProps => concatStyleSetsWithProps(props, { root: { maxWidth: 250 }, field: { backgroundColor: "pink"}}, props.styles)} />;
}

const TextFieldExample= () => (<MyTextField readOnly value="My text field" styles={{field: { fontWeight: 600}}} />);

const ExampleWrapper = () => <Fabric><TextFieldExample /></Fabric>;
ReactDOM.render(<ExampleWrapper />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

https://codepen.io/onlyann/pen/yLNXvPd?editors=1111